# Laravel 11 middleware not found inside App\Http

Tags: laravel, laravel-11

I need to bypass the CSRF token because I'm receiving data from a server, specifically from a payment page. I want to disable the CSRF token for a specific route, but in Laravel 11, I can't find the middleware folder. Where can I disable the CSRF token for a specific route in Laravel 11?

Comment: did you read the documentation for CSRF and exluding URIs from CSRF Protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 11 removes the `app/Http/Middleware` directory and other directories like `app/Exceptions` to clean up the structure. Instead, it's part of the Laravel framework's core code in the /vendor directory.

However, you should be able to directly disable CSRF protection for specific routes in the `routes/web.php` file using the `withoutMiddleware` method.

```php
Route::post('your/route/here', 'YourController@yourMethod')->withoutMiddleware([\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class]);
```

Replace `'your/route/here'` and `'YourController@yourMethod'` with the route and controller method you want to exclude from CSRF protection. If you have more routes to exclude, you can similarly add them.

[Laravel 11.x documentaton](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#excluding-middleware)

You can also exclude specific routes by providing their URIs to the `validateCsrfTokens` method in your application's `bootstrap/app.php` file.

```
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ]);
})
```

[Laravel 11.x documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)